# Mute ALL Audio on a Page

Tags: html

I have a landing page where the user can Login and signup and in the background is a Trailer for the site. The video has audio, and is a .mp4 file.

My main goal is to get a feature where the user can click a certain button and all page audio will be muted.

Many thanks

---HTML WITH VIDEO---

```
<div class="Main animated fadeIn">
        <!--To make the Site Unique, I have included Several Trailers for the Main Landing Page !-->
         <video autoplay="" id="bgvid" loop="" poster="polina.jpg"><source src=
        "img/indexMV.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="img/indexMV.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_muted

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="mute_all">Mute all</button> | 
<button id="unmute_all">UnMute all</button>
<br/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       /*** Mute all ***/
       $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){

          /*** Mute all video and audio on page ***/
          $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
             /*** Do it here globally ***/
             $(this).prop('muted', true);
          });

       });
      
       /*** UnMute all ***/
       $('#unmute_all').on('click',function(){

          /*** Un Mute all video and audio on page ***/
          $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
             /*** Do it here globally ***/
             $(this).prop('muted', false);
          });

       });
      
      
    });
    </script>
    <h4>Video</h4>
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
      
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    
    <br/>
<h4>AUdio</h4>
    
    <audio width="320" height="176" controls>
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg">      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get a reference to your video and you can mute/unmute it

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
vid.muted = true; // to mute
vid.muted = false; // to unmute
```

Comment: what if there are several videos on the document?

Comment: @Ark74 each video has its unique id, so you refer to each one by getElementById. or you could get all videos (var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');) and iterate on each and mute/unmute. in jquery you could $('video').prop('muted', true); to mute all vids.

Comment: Thanks, indeed at the end, that was they way I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to be able to mute any and all sources of audio, then you'll need to be able to collect references to all instances of video and/or audio playing. This is what this demo does:

- Plays/Pauses 5 videos individually or all at once.
- Mute/Unmute volume individually or all at once.

This is the process:

- Make a NodeList (`vPlayers`) of all video elements with the class of `.vPlayer`.
- Take the NodeList (`vPlayers`) and convert it into an array (`vArray`).
- EventListeners are added to the buttons, `vPlay` and `vMute` and once triggered, by a click, the callback function will iterate through the `vArray`.
- Each video element (`.vPlayer` a.k.a. `vArray[i]`) will be checked:

  - to see if it's playing a video (`playToggle` function), or ...
  - to see if it's muted (`muteToggle` function).
- After the preliminary status check, `playToggle` and `muteToggle` will play/pause and mute/unmute each `vPlayer` according to `vPlayer`'s state.

```js
const vids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("video"));
const vControl = document.forms.vControl;
const vC = vControl.elements;

const vPlay = vC.vPlay;
vPlay.addEventListener('click', playToggle);

function playToggle(e) {
  e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent === '▶️' ? '⏸️' : '▶️';
  vids.forEach(v => v.paused ? v.play() : v.pause());
}

const vMute = vC.vMute;
vMute.addEventListener('click', muteToggle);

function muteToggle(e) {
  e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent === '' ? '' : '';
  vids.forEach(v => {
    if (v.muted) {
      v.muted = false;
    } else {
      v.muted = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 54px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font: 300 2.5ch/1 'Consolas';
  color: #EEE;
  background: rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.25);
  border: 3px outset grey;
  border-radius: 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #00D;
  border: 3px inset blue;
}

.vBox {
  display: table-cell;
}

#vControl {
  width: 295px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-table;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="vBox">
  <video class="vPlayer" poster="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs21s3.png" width="320" height="180" controls>
    <source src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs21s3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <video class="vPlayer" poster="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs12s3.png" width="320" height="180" controls>
    <source src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs12s3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <form id="vControl" name="vControl">
    <fieldset>
      <button id="vPlay" type='button'>▶️</button>
      <button id="vMute" type='button'></button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: what about `new Audio(url)`?

Comment: OP has video so I'm going off of the assumption that video will be playing along with the audio. I just tested my example and found a mistake, thanks for the comment.